# Adding two submatrices in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, sum, submatrix

I have a `5x5` matrix M = magic(5)`and I must add two sub-matrices of it (using the`sum`command) and store it in`G`, they are:

`M(1:3,1:3)` and `M(3:5,3:5)`

And I wrote this, but I', not sure if it's correct,

```
G=sum(M([1:3,1:3],[3:5,3:5]));
```

Comment: Practice makes perfect. Why don't you experiment in the Command Window and see if what you get is correct?

Comment: You may be overcomplicating things... consider using the good old `+` operator for matrices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you could easily accomplish your goal with `+`.

```
 M = magic(5);
 A = M(1:3,1:3);
 B = M(3:5,3:5);
 G = A + B;
```

It could get a little complicated if you want to use `sum`,

```
C(:,:,1) = A;
C(:,:,2) = B;
G = sum(C,3);
```